# Problem with Bubble sort on a doubly link list

Tags: java

Ive been attempting to solve this and it is sorting some of my nodes but not all and i dont know why, and for some reason it changes the first node with my last node and cant figure that out too. I dont know if there is something wrong with my for loops. Also, getValue() just returns the object in the Node, this is my outputs

Linked List Data
9
5
8
6
10
4

Linked List Data
10
5
6
8
4
10

First is my unsorted list and the second list is me trying to sort it

```
public void BubbleSort4()
  {
      Node<T> temp, temp2,temp3;
      temp = front;
      temp3 = front;

      for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
      {
          temp2 = temp.getNext();
          Comparable comp = temp.getValue();

          for(int scan = 0; scan < i-1; scan++)
          {
              if(comp.compareTo(temp2.getValue()) > 0)
              {
                  temp3.setValue(temp.getValue());

                  temp.setValue(temp2.getValue());
                  temp2.setValue(temp3.getValue());

              }
          }
          temp = temp.getNext();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Put temp2=temp2.getNext() in your inner for loop

Answer (score 0):

Put `temp2=temp2.getNext()
comp=temp.getValue()` in your inner for loop and also post your full program to work on it fully.

```
public void BubbleSort4()
{
  Node<T> temp, temp2,temp3;
  temp = front;
  temp3 = front;

  for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
  {
      temp2 = temp.getNext();
      Comparable comp = temp.getValue();

      for(int scan = 0; scan <= i-1; scan++)
      {
          if(comp.compareTo(temp2.getValue()) > 0)
          {
              temp3.setValue(temp.getValue());

              temp.setValue(temp2.getValue());
              temp2.setValue(temp3.getValue());

          }

          temp2=temp2.getNext();
          comp=temp.getValue();
      }
      temp = temp.getNext();
  }
```

}

I would further update my answer.Dont rush to downvote.Please post your full program will work with that and verify my explanation.For now test this

Comment: Ok that works for the help, i didnt know i had to update comp everytime, this now sorts it, one small problem still, it changes my first input with my last one, Linked List Data
9
5
8
6
10
4

Linked List Data
10
4
5
6
8
10

Comment: I would post the full problem but there is so much code in the program that i think it better not to

Comment: @Bob  With out providing what your front is holding data or how data is read from input I cant test my code written. Try to provide more details. Edited with one more change check.Also If the answer manages to answer your question or help you in any way kindly upvote or accept